# 502 error with Django / nginx / uwsgi

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I'm getting really stressed out because i'm trying to get this site running on my ubuntu server. I'm just a front-ender trying to host things by myself. I think i almost got it down. But still getting 502 bad gateway error when visiting the domain.

This is my project tree:

```
-- var
    -- www
        -- stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek
            |-- env/
            |-- logs/
                |-- access.log
                |-- error.log
                `-- uwsgi.log
            |-- conf/
            |   |-- stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek.sock
            |   `-- uwsgi.ini
            `-- public/
                |-- manage.py
                |-- media/
                |-- project.db
                |-- requirements.txt
                |-- static/
                `-- website/
                    |-- dev/
                    |-- gulp/
                    |-- gulpfile.js
                    |-- package.json
                    |-- settings.py
                    |-- static/
                    |-- templates/
                    |-- urls.py
                    `-- wsgi.py
```

My uwsgi ini file:
`/var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/conf/uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
# variables
projectname = stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek
projectdomain = stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek.nl 
base = /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek

# config
chdir = %(base)/public
home = %(base)/env
wsgi-file = %(base)/public/website/wsgi.py

master = True
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/conf/%(projectname).sock
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true

logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log
```

My nginx config:
`/etc/nginx/sites-available/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek.nl www.stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek.nl;

    root /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/;
    access_log /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/logs/error.log;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/public/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/public/media/;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/www/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek/conf/stacaravanverhuurgroesbeek.sock;
    }
}
```

I also symlinked this file to `sites-enabled`.

And my startup script:
`/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

```
# Emperor uWSGI script

description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid bastard
setgid bastard

exec uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

Also everytime I changed something I restarted both nginx and uwsgi, with no effect.

I really hope someone can see what the problem is in my setup.

Comment: Is your wsgi config linked to vassals? How is the emperor finding your config?

Comment: @electrometro yes, I symlinked it to the vassals dir..

Comment: Should that unix socket pathname have three slashes? Usually one will do.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried both before, saw the three slashes in a post somewhere.. For now I also changed it back to one slash with still no effect :(

Comment: Is the .sock file created? If yes, try to delete it, and restart nginx.

Comment: Could not edit my comment any more....What does the Nginx log file say?

Comment: Did you take a look at your log files? You should be able to see what goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should set upstream in Nginx config since you're going to proxy all requests to uWSGI. E.g.:

```
upstream uwsgi_app {
    server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # взаимодействие  
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_app;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
    ...
}
```

If it won't work please provide uWSGI log also to make sure that reqquest actually reach uWSGI and no error occured.